# How to run python script inside vim?

Tags: vim, vi

I know we can run `a.py` in vim using commands:

```
:! python a.py    " method 1
:! python %       " method 2
```

We can also set key binding to run python script as:

```
autocmd! FileType python nmap ,r :!clear; python %<CR>
```

Now the problem is if we have to pass the arguments, I tried to create a command like this:

```
command py !python %   " This does not work!!
```

**Required**:
`:py arg1 arg2` should run python script with arguments arg1 and arg2, i.e. `python a.py arg1 arg2`

Example python script:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
```

I am using vim in Macbook Pro.

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
```

Comment: All user-defined commands must start with a capital letter. Thus, you are not permitted to define `:py`, but can define `:Py`. `:help user-cmd-ambiguous`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
command! -nargs=* Py !python % <args>
```

[`-nargs=*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#E176) allows any number of arguments (0, 1, or many). `<args>` pastes command-line arguments into the command.